# how to convert multybyte to wide char on mac

Tags: c++, macos, unicode

I'm now trying to convert some mutibyte chars(encoded in code page gb-2312) to UTF-16, is there functions like MultiBytetoWideChar on windows?

I only found a library called iconv, is there other functions?

Thank you!

Comment: `mbtowc()` from stdlib, `iconv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ICU library. Also, you can write your own function to convert to UTF-16.

If you want to use Objective-C If you can convert string to NSString, then you can easily convert to other encodings using -cStringUsingEncoding method.

Comment: Hi, I'm using c++, it seems iconv can do the work. But the situation is a little more tricky. I do not know the code page of the multibyte chars. I'm wondering the translation can be done via locale and region of the mac system?

Comment: ICU has codepage detection. http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection